# How to create batch file for java-quartz cron job

Tags: java, batch-file, cron, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to write a cron job using java quartz and triggering through windows batch file  because after so much searching there is no standalone particularly for java-quartz

Comment: **No** , and *because after so much searching there is no standalone particularly for java-quartz* please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

"So much searching"?  [This](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html) was the first link returned by Google.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to execute  java process as a windows service. If that is correct, wrap your java service (could be quartz as well) using [tanuki](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) wrapper and can install it as windows service. Or as @duffymo suggesting you can also use cron trigger too.

Comment: Thankz for the suggestion and yes java process as windows service this is the case what iam searching for well let me try this wrapper as for duffymo its very clear for linux platform